# Motorola 68000 assembly comparing numbers

Tags: assembly, conditional-statements, motorola, 68000

The program that I am in the process of writing takes input in the form of a single digit number followed by a space followed by a two digit number. The program will take the two numbers and add them together, reduce number by 7s until less than 7, and associate that number with a day of the week. Here is what I have:

```
start:  initIO                  * Initialize (required for I/O)
    setEVT          * Error handling routines
*   initF           * For floating point macros only       

    linein  buffer          *reads in values
    cvta2   buffer,#1       *provided macro to convert ascii to num, read first digit only
    move.b  D0,D1           *Store value in D1
    cvta2   buffer+2,#2     *read the next two digits after space
    move.b  D0,D2           *store
    add.b   D1,D2           *add them together (I can probably use just one register here)
```

here is the trouble:

```
for:    cmp.w   week, D2 *<<<<< This is saying invalid syntax, I want to see if the number provided is greater than 7, if not branch out to the next section
```

/trouble

```
    ble done
    subq.w  #7,D2        *If num>7, sub 7

done:   

    lineout dmsg

        break                   * Terminate execution
*
*----------------------------------------------------------------------
*       Storage declarations

buffer: dc.b    80
dmsg:   dc.b    'Done',0
week:   dc.b    $7    *If combined value is greater than this, sub 7
*These are the values to check against to get correct reply
sun:    dc.b    $1
mon:    dc.b    $2
tues:   dc.b    $3
weds:   dc.b    $4
thurs:  dc.b    $5
fri:    dc.b    $6
sat:    dc.b    $7
*These are the responses for the output
sunr:   dc.b    'Sunday',0
monr:   dc.b    'Monday',0
tuesr:  dc.b    'Tueday',0
wedsr:  dc.b    'Wednesday',0
thursr: dc.b    'Thursday',0
frir:   dc.b    'Friday',0
satr:   dc.b    'Saturday',0

        end
```

There will be more code when I figure out how to make the comparison above, but it will be the same sort of comparison just using the result against the days of the week values in order to provide the correct response.

I have tried using the various forms of cmp (cmpa, cmpi.w/l, etc), but I cannot seem to find a method that allows me to compare the two values. Would I have to load the value I labeled "week" into a register before trying to compare it or something like that?

Examples of I/O:

Input:

> 1 10

Output:

> "Wednesday"

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into the question; post it as an answer. (and roll back your edit.)

Comment: Even though the problem code is still there and separate from the working code? Can do.

Comment: Yes, answering the question within the question defeats the Q&A format, and puts your own answer in a special place above others where voting can't raise the best answers to the top.  (Barely matters for debug-help questions since they unfortunately rarely have much future value; it's hard for other people to search and find the right question when they don't know what their problem is either.)  Anyway, thanks for tidying up your question, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to perform a comparison with an unsupported addressing mode (in your example the 'week' operand is not an immediate value, but a memory address).

To compare D2 with 7 you can use cmpi (compare immediate):

```
cmpi.b #7,d2
```

In case you need the operand to be a variable, you must load it into a register first:

```
lea week,a0
...
cmp.b (a0),d2
```

Also make sure the operand size in the cmp instruction matches the size of your data

Comment: This is loading the address of the label into a0, so I think I just need to figure out the correct syntax to load the value at that address instead and I should be good.

Comment: @JeremyH. You don't actually need `week` to change at run-time, so instead of storing it in memory, define it as an assembler constant.  (I forget m68k syntax, but something like `week equ 7` so when you write `cmpi.w week, d2` it's equivalent to writing `cmpi.w #7, d2`.

Comment: @JeremyH.: And BTW, m68k addressing modes: http://moss.csc.ncsu.edu/~mueller/codeopt/codeopt00/notes/addmode.html.  Absolute (and PC-relative) addressing modes do exist.  Maybe your assembler is complaining because the `week` label is followed by a `dc.b` but you're doing a word load?

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the guidance. I got the program up on two feet finally. There is some optimization yet to be done, but that's outside the scope of this forum. I ended up using your equ for the week and I will check out your website. Thanks again!

Comment: @JeremyH.: heh, not "my" website, just the first google hit for `m68k addressing modes`.  Handy that m68k `equ` uses the same syntax as NASM.  The first assembly language I learned was m68k when I had an Atari ST, but I haven't used it for almost 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit(Working code for problem with the caveat that it is not optimized):**

```
start:  initIO                  * Initialize (required for I/O)
    setEVT          * Error handling routines
*   initF           * For floating point macros only    

    linein  buffer
    cvta2   buffer,#1   
    move.l  D0,D1
    cvta2   buffer+2,#2
    move.l  D0,D2
    add.l   D1,D2    

    divu.w  #$0007,D2   

    lsr.l   #$08,D2 *Shift remainder
    lsr.l   #$08,D2    

    move.w  sun,A2
    cmp.w   A2,D2
    BNE monday
    lineout sunr
    BEQ end

monday: 
    move.w  mon,A2
    cmp.w   A2,D2
    BNE tuesda
    lineout monr
    BEQ end    

tuesda: 
    move.w  tues,A2
    cmp.w   A2,D2
    BNE wednes
    lineout tuesr
    BEQ end    

wednes: 
    move.w  weds,A2
    cmp.w   A2,D2
    BNE thursd
    lineout wedsr
    BEQ end    

thursd: 
    move.w  thurs,A2
    cmp.w   A2,D2
    BNE friday
    lineout thursr
    BEQ end    

friday: 
    move.w  fri,A2
    cmp.w   A2,D2
    BNE saturd
    lineout frir
    BEQ end    

saturd: 
    lineout satr
    BEQ end    

end:    
        break                   * Terminate execution
*
*----------------------------------------------------------------------
*       Storage declarations

buffer: dc.b    80
wkmsg:  dc.w    'The day of the week is '
week:   equ $7
sun:    dc.w    $1
mon:    dc.w    $2
tues:   dc.w    $3
weds:   dc.w    $4
thurs:  dc.w    $5
fri:    dc.w    $6
sat:    dc.w    $7
sunr:   dc.w    'Sunday',0
monr:   dc.w    'Monday',0
tuesr:  dc.w    'Tueday',0
wedsr:  dc.w    'Wednesday',0
thursr: dc.w    'Thursday',0
frir:   dc.w    'Friday',0
satr:   dc.w    'Saturday',0

        end
```

Comment: `BEQ end` is a conditional branch, right?  Surely it should be an unconditional jump, instead of conditional on the flags left by `lineout`.

Comment: You already know this isn't optimized, but the biggest one that jumps out at me is that you could do one bounds-check and then a table lookup from a table of pointers to strings.  So instead of `$1`, `$2`, etc. in memory, you'd have `dc.w $sunr, $monr, ...` (or whatever the right syntax is for having the address of another label as data), so you do an indexed load into A2 or something, then `lineout A2`.

Comment: Also, you really don't need `$1` to be stored in  a `dc.w`.  The 1-7 constants could be `equ` constants as well.  Also, I think you forgot the `, 0` after `wkmsg`, but if the number of characters is odd, then using `dc.w` saved you from yourself by padding with a zero out to a whole number of Words.